# Fixed points of successive differentiation.

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be a function and
$$\mathfrak{F}:C^{\infty}\rightarrow C^{\infty} : f(x)\mapsto\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}$$
when it exists. Then what is the domain of $\mathfrak{F}$?

I know that functions $g(x)=ae^x$ are in the domain and that polynomials are there too but does it contain anything else?

Edit : I suppose the norm in $C^\infty$ can be taken as
$$\parallel f\parallel_{C^\infty}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\;\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\;\left|\frac{d^kf}{dx^k}\right|$$